# Request method 'POST' not supported spring mvc securtity registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I know that this question was asked a million times before, but i looked through a lot of them and nothing seems to help so i'm asking my own. I'm trying to register new user as it is shown in spring.io guides but iget this error. 
My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserRegistrationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView registration() {

        logger.info("registration page shown");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("userForm", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPassword());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

}
```

my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Registration</h1>
            <form th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${userForm}" method="post" class="form-signin">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>

                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                                        autofocus="true"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <input type="password"  th:field="*{password}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <input type="password" th:field="*{confirmPassword}" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Confirm your password"/>
                        </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form:form>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any advice would be apreciated.

Comment: You added a second `/registration` to your POST method, so the path is `/registration/registration`. Read your startup logs, and you'll see all the mappings.

Comment: A few notes: Prefer constructor injection to field injection. Good choice on going with Thymeleaf for new projects. Consider using the new `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` composite annotations. When using `ModelAndView`, it's conventional to use `new ModelAndView("registration")`.